# reading in data in sas works on some platforms and not on others

Tags: sas, delimiter

Why does this code not work in SAS University Edition even though it works on SAS 9.4 for Windows?

```
DATA HealthPlan;
  INFILE DATALINES FIRSTOBS = 2;
  INPUT Department :$10. HealthPlan $; 
  DATALINES;
Department  HealthPlan
Accounting  A
Food    A
Security    B
;
RUN;
```

It seems to be something with the treatment of delimiters. If I add `DLM = '09'x`, then it will work on University Edition, but otherwise the output from my log file is as follows:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         DATA HealthPlan;
 74           INFILE DATALINES FIRSTOBS = 2;
 75           INPUT Department :$10. HealthPlan $;
 76           DATALINES;

 NOTE: LOST CARD.
 RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                     
 81         ;
 Department=SecurityB HealthPlan=  _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
 NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
 NOTE: The data set WORK.HEALTHPLAN has 1 observations and 2 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds


 81         ;
 82         RUN;
 83         
 84         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 97
```

Could it be something with the encoding?

Comment: Which OS is University edition on?

Comment: @vasja Red Hat 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the SAS/Studio editor is not smart enough to replace tabs with spaces before passing the code to SAS to execute.

You really shouldn't be putting tabs into your SAS programs anyway and definitely not in the middle of lines of in-line data.

If the tabs got into the data lines because you pasted from cells copied from Excel then if you change your editor preferences settings in SAS/Studio to substitute tabs with spaces then the tabs will be replaced when you paste into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

It could be about line-endings of the code written.
In linux there's LF (line feed) while in windows CRLF (both carriage return and line feed) are expected. If you are sharing exact same code it could be misinterpreted.
Maybe just have a look at code in some editor showing non-printable characters.

When reading/writing files the related SAS option is [TERMSTR option](http://support.sas.com/kb/14/178.html), however does not apply to datalines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EXPANDTABS INFILE statement option.  It works sometimes because some editors expand tabs when you submit others don't.